# BigDecimal - Basic Calculations

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal

```
require 'bigdecimal'

sum = BigDecimal.new("2.33")

sum1 = BigDecimal.new("3.68")

sum2 = sum + sum1

puts sum2
# 0.601E1

# my attempt at converting scientific notation
puts sum2.to_i
# 6
```

1. How do I convert `0.601E1` to `6.1` in `BigDecimal`?
2. Where can I find some basic `BigDecimal` resources?
3. Are there any other *basic* `BigDecimal` concepts that I should keep in mind?

Comment: Yes, you can use `puts #to_f` to print a number in a human notation, but it only works for small and low precision numbers. Try `BigDecimal('1'*20).to_f` or `BigDecimal('0.'+'5'*20).to_f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You have to call `#to_s` with `paramter 'F'`.

```
sum2.to_s('F')
```

The solutions others have given you are not great, if you convert BigDecimal to the immediate float, you **lose precision.**

2) [Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) is pretty good.

3) The important concept is: Do not convert immediate results you calculate using BigDecimal to Float (which is IEE floating point). You are going to destroy all the effort this way. This is such a simple concept to grasp, yet a lot of people fail to.

Comment: Why downvotes? Have you even tried out this solution? This is the only valid way to print out the number that works, no matter how big the number is. Try this: `BigDecimal('1'*20).to_f`

Comment: Thank you very much, sir!  I have been looking all over for such an answer.  I have read through the documentation and am apparently too stupid to make heads or tails of it.  I'll give it a whirl again, however.

Comment: Nope, it is just well-hidden or not so obvious. :) I wouldn't have known it, unless I had used it before.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a look at [this method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_f)
2. There are a handful of good examples [inlined in the docs themselves](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html), illustrating how to use some of the different calls.
3. Once again, the docs have a bunch of good info -- one to keep in mind is that it's [possible to have both positive and negative zeroes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#label-Positive+and+negative+zero)

Sorry, I realize everything here points to the docs, but it's honestly the first place I look when I'm looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (BigDecimal.new("2.33") + BigDecimal.new("3.68")).to_f
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one try using [`BigDecimal#to_f`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_f):

```
require 'bigdecimal'

sum = BigDecimal.new("2.33")

sum1 = BigDecimal.new("3.68")

sum2 = sum + sum1
puts sum2.to_f
# >> 6.01
```